# Glassfish 4: jasper - osgi package doesn't exist

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, glassfish, osgi

I use glassfish 4.0.1 + openjdk 8. All my application is osgi based. I have a wab and jsp in it with scriptlets. These scriplets import some classes. These classes are in another budnles. These classes exist and exported (other bundles, not wab use them without problem).

However I get the following error:

> Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
>   org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Error in Javac compilation
>   for JSP
>
> PWC6199: Generated servlet error: package com.mycom.test does not
>   exist
>
> PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 36 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
>   PWC6199: Generated servlet error: cannot find symbol   symbol:   class
>   Foo   location: class org.apache.jsp....index_jsp

I've checked several times - necessary packages are in Inport-package list. But jasper doesn't see them.

Besides, I have in my pom

```
 <plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.3</version>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
           <manifestFile>
           ${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
                        </manifestFile>
           <manifestEntries>
           <Bundle-ClassPath>WEB-INF/classes/</Bundle-ClassPath>
          </manifestEntries>
        </archive>
     <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, this is not the solution but the explanation of this bug.

https://www.java.net/forum/topic/glassfish/glassfish/should-jsps-wab-deployment-have-access-external-osgi-bundle-classes

and

https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-11208